# Mysql group based on other column

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
---------------------
|user_id|   product  |
---------------------
|   1   |     A      |
---------------------
|   1   |     A      |
---------------------
|   1   |     B      |
---------------------
|   2   |     A      |
---------------------
|   2   |     B      |
---------------------
|   3   |     A      |
---------------------
|   3   |     B      |
---------------------
|   3   |     B      |
---------------------
|   3   |     C      |
---------------------
|   3   |     D      |
---------------------
```

I need to know each user how many have unique products (see below)

```
-----------------------
|user_id|unique_product|
-----------------------|
|   1   |     2        |
-----------------------|
|   2   |     2        |
-----------------------|
|   3   |     4        |
-----------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNT and DISTINCT

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `user_id` INTEGER,
>   `product` VARCHAR(1)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`user_id`, `product`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'A'),
>   ('1', 'A'),
>   ('1', 'B'),
>   ('2', 'A'),
>   ('2', 'B'),
>   ('3', 'A'),
>   ('3', 'B'),
>   ('3', 'B'),
>   ('3', 'C'),
>   ('3', 'D');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `user_id`, COUNT(DISTINCT `product`) FROM table1 GROUP BY `user_id`
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | COUNT(DISTINCT `product`)
> ------: | ------------------------:
>       1 |                         2
>       2 |                         2
>       3 |                         4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=54f8626b78571335422e932f5e8c3e8a)*